# How to access Internal hard disk partitions in ubuntu live session?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, hard-drive, partitioning

I have booted through USB into the OS: ubuntu 21

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~/Desktop$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 21.04
Release:    21.04
Codename:   hirsute
```

After that, there are no entries for my internal hard disk in the media folder nor in the `mnt`.

No entry for 1 TB in the below commands also.

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~/Desktop$ df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
tmpfs           3.1G  2.1M  3.1G   1% /run
/dev/sda1        29G  2.7G   26G  10% /cdrom
/cow             16G  118M   16G   1% /
tmpfs            16G     0   16G   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs           5.0M  8.0K  5.0M   1% /run/lock
tmpfs           4.0M     0  4.0M   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
tmpfs            16G     0   16G   0% /tmp
tmpfs           3.1G  160K  3.1G   1% /run/user/999
ubuntu@ubuntu:~/Desktop$ fdisk -l
fdisk: cannot open /dev/loop0: Permission denied
fdisk: cannot open /dev/loop1: Permission denied
fdisk: cannot open /dev/loop2: Permission denied
fdisk: cannot open /dev/loop3: Permission denied
fdisk: cannot open /dev/loop4: Permission denied
fdisk: cannot open /dev/loop5: Permission denied
fdisk: cannot open /dev/sda: Permission denied
```

Some similar posts shown to access them using some commands but before that they mentioned it should be visible in `df -h`, but it isn't displayed
Any suggestions I need to follow to access them?

Not visible in the explorer also:

[image]

Comment: Do you absolutely want to know how to do this in the terminal? They are easily accessible through GUI in the file explorer.

Comment: In the file explorer also it is not showing, can you please guide me the steps

Comment: File explorer → _Other locations_ in the left pane

Comment: It is not visible there, the Hard disk is not mounted. And there is no problem in hardware as I can boot to windows 10(OS installed on that disk)

Comment: Are you using Bitlocker, VeraCrypt or some other form of disk encryption?

Comment: No we still didnit enable bit locker,but in plan to. Please suggest in both cases

Comment: Can you post a screenshot from GParted?

Comment: What is the output of `lsblk`? It seems there is /dev/sda which could be your drive.

Comment: Is it a SATA drive or NVMe drive? Maybe it is a latter one that got hidden by the Intel RST remapping crap?

Answer (score 0):

Internal drives are usually not mounted automatically on boot. What is the output of `lsblk`? There seems to be /dev/sda, which is probably the drive with your wanted partition.

If you find your drive with `lsblk` just mount it with

```
sudo mount /dev/sdaX /mnt
```

you need to replace the X with the partition number.

Comment: `/dev/sda1        29G  2.7G   26G  10% /cdrom`. `lsblk` is a nice/better alternative to `fdisk -l`, but it probably won't help if you don't see the device being listed in the latter.